# Working on a Navigation Bar and Having Trouble with CSS file Integration

Tags: html, css

Currently, I'm working on a basic navigation bar that changes the color of the text when clicked to go to a new page (So text on one page is a different color than text on another). I started the project ultimately using multiple CSS files to get the result I am looking for but it is horrendously inefficient. Obviously "if" statements don't exist in CSS but are there a way to call on an action if a certain page is loaded.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Project</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li class="shop"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li class="wname"><a href="index.html">Website Name</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    color: rgba(102, 102, 102, .5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wname {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #F68404;
    font-weight: 200;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #F68404;
}

li:active {
    color: #F68404;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #F68404;
}

li:hover {
    color: #F68404;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*.jumbotron {
    background: url("https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/city-wallpaper-11.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 800px;
}

.main {
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-main {
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

.btn-main:hover {
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: #000;
    border: solid 1px aliceblue;
}*/

/*Class Rules for all anchors/hyperlinks*/
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

I would appreciate any help,
Jordan

Comment: Hi JordanMorris. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can click on the comment and leave some comments. Once you get an answer, and it looks good or useful, you should accept it, after 15 mins of posting the question, as a courtesy of thanks. Let me know in the comments, if you got the answer.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, all navigation items should change color, on different pages? If so, you can simple add multiple (2 in this case) classes to navigation element. One class will hold all mutual characteristics for navigation (on all pages), and another one will define color, for different pages... Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rptrhpoo/1/ So, all can be defined in one css file, you will just have small changes in html...

Comment: @sinisake What the?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, this is how i undersand question: 'So text on one page is a different color than text on another' This could mean many different things... Also, OP mentioned different CSS files, too... i assume that all nav items change color (one page - one color). My assumption could be wrong... but, waiting for clarification.... And yes i didn't see anything in question what could be related to 'active link' problem... Who knows... :)

Comment: @sinisake Yea yea... Agreed with you. But your comment was like, what the for me... That's why.

Answer (score 0):

Change this rule to add an active class as well:

```
li.active,
li:hover {
  color: #F68404;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

And in your individual pages, use the class for the `<li>`. Let's say, in the Shop page, use this code:

```
<li class="shop active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
```

This is because, you aren't using anything that checks the location and does stuff. Also, you aren't using any back end applications, which generate dynamic header, based on the URL.